# Using sync to update pivot tables with Laravel's Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, relationships

I'm trying to update my pivot table with the following.

```
// Controller

if ( Input::has( 'roles' ) )
{
    $user = $this->user->find( $id );

    $user->roles()->sync( Input::get('roles') );

    return Redirect::back()->with( 'success', 'You have successfully updated the user' );
}


// Model

public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Roles', 'users_roles', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```

When the user updates their roles it goes through fine however only 1 record is updated or written and the role_id is 0.

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Presumably `Input::get('roles)` returns an `array<integer>`, all of which are valid `role_id`s? If not, that's probably your problem.

Comment: @alexrussell Sometimes I can't see the wood for the trees, it wasn't an array of integers it was returning, that was my problem! Thanks man

Comment: Hehe no problem. You should accept your answer too so it's marked as the official answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I wasn't passing an array of integers through to the sync method so I amended this to...

```
$user->roles()->sync( array_keys( Input::get( 'roles' ) ) );
```

Thanks to @alexrussell